# Program for editing exe (PECOFF) files

Tags: windows, editing

I need a program to edit exe files.
For example to rewrite .text section in assembly or edit data .section.
Do you know anything free suitable for me ?

Comment: Today I'd recommend Hopper to hobbyists. Unfortunately the Windows version was discontinued, but it can be run inside a Linux VM to disassemble a Windows binary.

Answer (score 2):

While IDA Pro is by fast the best, as Michael recommends, it's not free. Try something like [Ollydbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) instead.

Comment: Good point.  I upvoted you.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of PECOFF files, but I'm guessing since they're exe files you'll need a hex editor. I use [bvi](http://bvi.sourceforge.net/) for hex editing, but it helps to know vi editing commands to use it.

Comment: I need something which would change it into assembly

Answer (score 0):

You need to search for a "windows disassembler".

[IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) is one of them.

Comment: IDA pro isn't free, which is what the question asked for.

Comment: @Dentrasi even at the time of your comment there existed a freeware version of IDA which was capable of disassembling (32-bit) PE files for Windows.